# Geodesic distance discrepancies using proj

Tags: python, proj, pyproj

I have two positions represented as latitude,longitude pairs, and I'm trying to get the distance between them. I've 3 methods that all yield different results, where I think they should be VERY close. The methods are:

1. Converting the lat/lon to a Cartesian UTM system, and then using the Cartesian distance
2. pyproj.Geod
3. The "geod" command-line tool

For an arbitrary pair of points that are ~1km apart, I see:

```
diff utm:          1161.43346448816
diff geod:         1161.1017567084384
diff geod cmdline: 1163.971
```

This looks wrong. The UTM probably should be slightly off because the two Cartesian systems are slightly tilted, but is 30cm over 1km really how far off it should be?

The difference between pyproj.Geod and the "geod" cmdline tool makes even less sense. In theory they're doing the same thing, so the results should be identical.

A Python script to run the 3 methods, and print the ranges:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyproj
import numpy as np
import subprocess

lat0,lon0 = (31.4617, -83.4849)
lat1,lon1 = (31.4704, -83.4781)

zone = 1 + int((lon0 + 180) // 6)
print(f"zone: {zone}")

toutm = \
    pyproj.Proj(proj           = 'utm',
                zone           = zone,
                ellps          = 'WGS84',
                preserve_units = False # output in meters
                )

e0,n0 = toutm(lon0, lat0)
e1,n1 = toutm(lon1, lat1)


print(f"diff utm:          {np.sqrt((e0-e1)**2. + (n0-n1)**2.)}")
print(f"diff geod:         {pyproj.Geod(ellps = 'WGS84').inv( lon0,lat0,  lon1,lat1)[2]}")


cmd_input = f"{lat0} {lon0} {lat1} {lon1}"
cmd_output_range = subprocess.check_output( ("geod", "+ellps=WGS84", "-I", "+units=m"),
                                            input = cmd_input,
                                           encoding = "ascii").split()[-1]
print(f"diff geod cmdline: {cmd_output_range}")
```

Comment: What version of pyproj? What version of `geod`?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The UTM discrepancy is due to me not applying the UTM scale factor. And the "geod" cmdline tool discrepancy is due to using an ancient version of proj. This discrepancy disappears in proj 4.9.0. Commit: https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/commit/f1f1f9f2aea725663499f449961027df2b38e296